# Comparing Object Or Just IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a performance gain in comparing objects like this...

```
current_user.id == @user.id
```

versus this ...

```
current_user == @user
```

Also are there best-practice reasons for doing one over the other regardless of performance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but *barely*. [`ActiveRecord::Base#==`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-3D-3D) does this:

```
def ==(comparison_object)
  super ||
    comparison_object.instance_of?(self.class) &&
    id.present? &&
    comparison_object.id == id
end
```

Which essentially compares `id`s but ensures that the objects are of the same type, which you probably want since, for example, if you compared just `id`s they *could* be the same even though one is a `User` and another a `Product`.

In conclusion, comparing the model objects themselves is best.